# If and Set in a Batch file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd, set

I have a little problem :
I try to put a choice to delete all the text files in the folder, but it's a bit hard. Here's my code :

```
@echo off 
if not exist *.txt (
    echo Il n'y a pas de fichiers txt
) else (
    dir /b *.txt
:start
    echo voulez vous supprimer ces fichiers textes?
    set input=
    set /p input=Choice:
    if %input%==y goto 1
    if %input%==n goto 2
    @REM Veuillez appuyer sur "y" ou "n".
    @echo Le programme recommence.
    goto start

1:
    echo Fichiers supprimés 
2: 
    echo Fichiers non supprimés
)
```

I tried with choice, but I can do more things with set.

Thanks for any answer, and also excuse me for bad english.

P.S: The sentences in 1 and 2 means Files deleted/Undeleted files

Comment: First of all, your `else` is missing a `)`. Secondly, the `:` goes at the beginning of the label, not the end. And finally, because batch scripts run top-down, section :2 will always be performed after :1 is run unless you add an `exit /b` to the end of the :1 section.

Comment: You are also inside a code block which means your input variable will not expand correctly.  You will need to use delayed expansion for that variable.

Comment: @SomethingDark: the closing `)` is there - at the very end of the code. P.Habans: a `goto` breaks your code block, so this will never work as intended.

Comment: Oh jeez, I didn't even see that; my brain just automatically assumed it was a typo.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reorganized a your code (and did some small corrections). When dealing with env vars inside an `if` or `for` block you need to use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). Also when dealing with [labels](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html), at the end of each label you need an `goto :eof` statement, otherwise the interpreter will also execute the lines beyond that label (if any).

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if not exist *.txt (
    echo Il n'y a pas de fichiers txt.
) else (
    goto :start
)
goto :eof

:start
    dir /b *.txt
    echo voulez vous supprimer ces fichiers textes?
    set input=
    set /p input=Choice:
    if "!input!"=="y" goto :label1
    if "!input!"=="n" goto :label2
    @REM Veuillez appuyer sur "y" ou "n".
    @echo Le programme recommence.
    goto :start

:label1
    echo Fichiers supprimés
    goto :eof
:label2
    echo Fichiers non supprimés
    goto :eof
```